# Show a tooltip on the Close (X) button on the form

Tags: c#, forms, notify

I have a form, wherein I prohibit the user from closing it when the user clicks the <kbd>Close (X)</kbd> button. Is it possible to show a tooltip on the <kbd>Close (X)</kbd> button whenever it is clicked? I want to do it to notify the user why the form would not close.

I thought of a messagebox but then I thought it would be too annoying to close the messagebox every time you click the <kbd>Close (X)</kbd> button.

Is there a better way to notify the user, than what I'm trying to do?

EDIT:

This is my code for the FormClosing event

```
    private void InputForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (!mCloseReason)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a method that will save the inputs in the form. Once that method is finished, I need to automatically close the form. The *if-statement* will  be *true* once I call *this.Close()*, this means I can't close the form. That's why I used a variable called *mCloseReason* to be able to close the form automatically. Now, that's why I was asking if I can notify the user through a tooltip once the <kbd>Close (X)</kbd> button is clicked.

Comment: I’m not sure what the situation is, but would it be preferable to show the close button’s disabled state instead? A tooltip is a bit unusual.

Comment: No. I'm using DevExpress to apply a skin on the form, and the code snippet for not showing the close button doesn't work with DevExpress.

Comment: I think it is standard behaviour to allow a user to hit a cancel button to close a form whenever they want.  Otherwise, if they hit an OK or Apply button, but the input is not correct on other controls, that would be a good time to display an error message.  Here is a great article on UI design: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/fog0000000249.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default tooltip for the close(X) button is not editable without some hacking (and it is not practical).

Maybe what you could do is have a status field below your form, so when the user clicks the close button, it says in the status field "cannot close form (...)"

Or another idea is to have a message pop up somewhere on the form and go away after a little, indicating the form cannot be closed.

Another good idea was mentioned by Roger... just have a Close button somewhere on the form with a tooltip coded to it, and hide the forms' title bar?

Comment: I just placed a label near the bottom of the Close (X) button, made it invisible, and then show the tooltip there.